# Proof that Vec ++ [] == Vec?

Tags: agda

Is there a handy proof that:

```
++[] : ∀ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} {n} (vec : Vec A n) -> vec ++ [] ≡ vec
```

I am unable to even write the type of this proof, apparently, because

```
n != n Nat.+ Nat.zero of type ℕ
when checking that the expression vec has type
Vec A (n Nat.+ Nat.zero)
```

Edit: not a homework problem, and I looked in `Data.Vec.Properties` before posting. (I assumed that went without saying.) If this proof is in there, I couldn't find it, and so its name would be a great answer to this question.

Comment: Look in stdlib's `Data.Vec.Properties`. But also you're getting downvoted as this is likely an assignment problem?

Comment: This is not a homework problem; I am studying Agda on my own time, unrelated to my education. I was unable to find this in `Data.Vec.Properties`; if it's in there, I'd like to know what it's called. The only proofs I see in the stdlib related to `Vector._++_` are its being injective and its relationship with `lookup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed the case that

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

postulate
  ++[] : ∀ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} {n} (vec : Vec A n) -> vec ++ [] ≡ vec
```

doesn't type check due to `_≡_` expecting two values of definitionally the same types and `n + 0` equals `n` only propositionally and not definitionally (see [equality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equality) for details).

So you need a fancier equality than just `_≡_` and there's multiple options (disclaimer: I've never actually used any of those extensively).

1. Use heterogeneous equality:

   ```
    module Heterogeneous where
      open import Relation.Binary.HeterogeneousEquality
      open import Data.Nat.Properties

      ++[]₁ : ∀ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} {n} (vec : Vec A n) -> vec ++ [] ≅ vec
      ++[]₁ []      = refl
      ++[]₁ (x ∷ v) = icong (Vec _) (+-identityʳ _) (_∷_ x) (++[]₁ v)
   ```

However as you can see that requires having a proof of `∀ n -> n + 0 ≡ n`, which is awkward and is an unnecessary complication.

2. You can have a custom relation such as the [one](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Vec.Relation.Binary.Pointwise.Inductive.html#1226) used by the standard library:

   ```
    data Pointwise {a b ℓ} {A : Set a} {B : Set b} (_∼_ : REL A B ℓ) :
                   ∀ {m n} (xs : Vec A m) (ys : Vec B n) → Set (a ⊔ b ⊔ ℓ)
                   where
      []  : Pointwise _∼_ [] []
      _∷_ : ∀ {m n x y} {xs : Vec A m} {ys : Vec B n}
            (x∼y : x ∼ y) (xs∼ys : Pointwise _∼_ xs ys) →
            Pointwise _∼_ (x ∷ xs) (y ∷ ys)
   ```

With this `Pointwise _≡_` is your equality:

```
module Pointwise where
  open import Data.Vec.Relation.Binary.Pointwise.Inductive
  open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
 
  ++[]₂ : ∀ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} {n} (vec : Vec A n) -> Pointwise _≡_ (vec ++ []) vec
  ++[]₂ []      = []
  ++[]₂ (x ∷ v) = _≡_.refl ∷ ++[]₂ v
```

It's a good solution, but requires a dedicated relation (plus conversion functions to and from propositional equality etc) for each of your indexed data types, so it's pretty heavy.

3. Use "heteroindexed" equality:

   ```
    module Heteroindexed where
      infix 4 [_]_≅_

      data [_]_≅_ {ι α} {I : Set ι} {i} (A : I -> Set α) (x : A i) : ∀ {j} -> A j -> Set where
        refl : [ A ] x ≅ x

      cong
        : ∀ {ι κ α β} {I : Set ι} {K : Set κ}
            {A : I -> Set α} {B : K -> Set β}
            {f : I -> K} {i j : I} {x : A i} {y : A j}
        -> (h : {k : I} -> (z : A k) -> B (f k))
        -> [ A ] x ≅ y
        -> [ B ] h x ≅ h y
      cong _ refl = refl

      ++[]₃ : ∀ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} {n} (vec : Vec A n) -> [ Vec A ] vec ++ [] ≅ vec
      ++[]₃ []      = refl
      ++[]₃ (x ∷ v) = cong (_∷_ x) (++[]₃ v)
   ```

This is fine, but `cong` is pretty complicated and this solution only works for data types having a single index. If you have another data type but this time with two indices, you'll have to define another version of `[_]_≅_`, more awkward and with an even more complicated `cong` this time.

4. Use "telescopic" equality:

   ```
    module Telescopic where
      open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
      open import Data.Product

      ++[]₄ : ∀ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} {n} (vec : Vec A n) -> _≡_ {A = ∃ (Vec A)} (_ , vec ++ []) (_ , vec)
      ++[]₄ []      = refl
      ++[]₄ (x ∷ v) = cong (Data.Product.map _ (_∷_ x)) (++[]₄ v)
   ```

This one doesn't require any setup, so that's good, but you still have to introduce some name, because using `_≡_ {A = ∃ (Vec A)}` multiple times is way too clunky to be practical.

Comment: Surprised you didn't mention any solution using `subst` ?

Comment: @JacquesCarette having `subst` at the type-level is generally horrible, so I thought it wouldn't be worth spending time discussing it. Or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: I completely agree that `subst` is horrible, doubly so at the type level. It's just the first thing that most people pull out in this situation.